# Is there a way to remove the parenthesis that are automatically generated in CursorLoader()'s selection parameter?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

First of all, I was attempting to use a fts3 sqlite table for searching on Android but it doesn't work since it doesn't by default support parenthesis.

I noticed that the **CursorLoader()** automatically puts the selection parameter *(where clause)* within parenthesis when executing.

So my question is, is there a way to remove the parenthesis?

Any work-around, comments, or answers would be appreciated.

Comment: Um, `CursorLoader` does not work against a SQLite database. It works against a `ContentProvider`. `CursorLoader` does not put anything in parentheses -- the `ContentProvider` perhaps does, as part of its `query()` method. Also, Android's SQLite supports FTS3/FTS4 parentheses, at least as of Android 5.1.

Comment: hmm and if so is there a way then to fix parenthesis automatically being put with the query of a contentprovider since the query uses the same structure as the cursorloader().Well im trying to support 4.0 and up,

Comment: You are the one building the SQLite query, in your `ContentProvider`. Hence, you are the one putting the parentheses in, directly or indirectly. If you do not want to do that, fix your code in your provider's `query()` method to not put in the parentheses that you do not want.

Comment: well this is all thats happening in my content provider for query, I dont think I'm putting parenthesis. '
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        Cursor cursor;

        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case NOTES_LIST:
                qb.setTables(NotesModel.NotesTable.TABLE_NAME);
break;'

Comment: }cursor = qb.query(db,projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,sortOrder);
        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);//observer for loader
        return cursor;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `SQLiteQueryBuilder`. `SQLiteQueryBuilder` is what is adding your parentheses.

Your options are:

1. [Fork `SQLiteQueryBuilder`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.java) and modify your copy to not use parentheses here, or
2. Use `rawQuery()` on your `SQLiteDatabase`, perhaps by using `buildQuery()` or `buildQueryString()` on `SQLiteQueryBuilder` to give you the `String` of the query, which you then modify to eliminate the parentheses that are giving you trouble

Comment: 1+ for #2. You just answered a question I also have.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer for the question as it succeeds in removing the parenthesis. However, my fts3 table still doesn't function correctly, so it seems parenthesis might have not been the main issue.

Comment: @kenikun21: FWIW, [here is a sample app of mine](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/FTS) that demonstrates the use of FTS. It uses FTS4, but it may give you some ideas.